# Detecting frame-accurate seeking with HTML5 video

Tags: javascript, html, browser, html5-video

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298084/html5-frame-by-frame-viewing-frame-seeking), frame-by-frame video seeking is supported in several but not all browsers ([test page](http://www.massive-interactive.nl/html5_video/smpte_test_universal.html)).

If a user comes to my page, is there any reliable way to detect whether or not their browser supports frame-accurate seeking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up creating a small 1x4 video that shows a binary pattern each frame (0001 for frame 1, 0010 for frame two, etc), loading it in the background, and using `<canvas>` element to read the data and check for accuracy.